# how to show shapefile from directory in arcgis js

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I want to show shapefile to arcgis js. I'm using this https://github.com/Esri/add-shapefile-js but its must upload on browser. so how to load from directory or local folder. I tried this code.

```
   function file(){
   var namashp;
   namashp = 'http://localhost/addshapefile/shp.zip';
   generateFeatureCollection(namashp);
```

**Error** : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expand' of undefined